# Making asp:CheckBoxList Items Side By Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a problem and i couldn't find the solution on web. I'm using asp CheckBoxList but i have too many data to list. I want to list items like in 2 column in box area. I'm sharing an image. Please check it out. So how can i do something like that?

[image]

The important thing is; this checkboxlist filling dynamically from code behind. I dont have ListItem on html page. So i cant style them. Any idea?

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="AreaCheckBoxes" runat=server>

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`RepeatColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property to 2 and the [`RepeatLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `Table`.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="AreaCheckBoxes" 
                  RepeatColumns="2" 
                  RepeatLayout="Table" 
                  RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                  runat=server>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thank you!